# Kurento group call example : Can we record each individual user's mediapipeline separately?

Tags: java, kurento

In Kurento Group call example is it possible to record each individual user's mediapipeline separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can record each user's WebRTC media element separately. A couple of suggestions:

- Make sure you record in WEBM format, so you avoid transcoding
- Start recording once the media is flowing. You can do this by listening to the `MediaStateChanged` event, or checking the status of media in the WebRTC element for that participant.
- Consider recording your files in external storage, such as S3, to prevent running out of space

You'll have to connect the recorder to the `outgoingMedia` element, located in the [UserSession](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-group-call/src/main/java/org/kurento/tutorial/groupcall/UserSession.java#L52). You can add the recorder initialisation in the constructor, and the listener for the `MediaStatechangedEvent` similar to the [`IceCandidateListener`](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-group-call/src/main/java/org/kurento/tutorial/groupcall/UserSession.java#L64), so you start recording once media starts to flow between the client and the media server.